# Read fail with consistency one

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've got 3 nodes; 2 in datacenter 1 (node 1 and node 2) and 1 in datacenter 2 (node 3). Replication strategy: Network Topology, dc1:2, dc2: 1.

Initially I keep one of the nodes in dc1 off (node 2) and write 100 000 entries with consistency 2 (via c++ program). After writing, I shut down the node in datacenter 2 (node 3) and turn on node 2.

Now, if I try to read those 100 000 entries I had written (again via c++ program) with consistency set as ONE, I'm not able to read all those 100 000 entries i.e. I'm able to read only some of the entries. As I run the program again and again, my program fetches more and more entries.

I was expecting that since one of the 2 nodes which are up contains all the 100 000 entries, therefore, the read program should fetch all the entries in the first execution when the set consistency is ONE.

Is this related to read repair? I'm thinking that because the read repair is happening in the background, that is why, the node is not able to respond to all the queries? But nowhere could I find anything regarding this behavior.

Comment: Please stop using indian words as your measurement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run through the scenario.

During the write of 100K rows (DC1) Node1 and (DC2) Node3 took all the writes. As it was happening Node1 also might have taken hints for Node2 (DC1) for default 3 hours and then stop doing that.

Once Node2 comes back up online, unless a repair was run - it takes a bit to catch up through replay of hints. If the node was down for more than 3 hours, repair becomes mandatory.

During the reads, it can technically reach to any node in the cluster based on the loadbalancy policy used by driver. Unless specified to do "DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy", the read request might even reach any of the DC (DC1 or DC2 in this case). Since the consistency requested is "ONE", practically any ALIVE node can respond - NODE1 & NODE2 (DC1) in this case. So NODE2 may not even have all data and it can still respond with NULL value and thats why you received empty data sometimes and correct data some other time.

With consistency "ONE" read repair doesn't even happen, as there no other node to compare it with. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html) on it . Even in case of consistency "local_quorum" or "quorum" there is a **read_repair_chance** set at the table level which is default to 0.1. Which means only 10% of reads will trigger read_repair. This is to save performance by not triggering every time.  Think about it, if read repair can bring the table entirely consistent across nodes, then why does "nodetool repair" even exist?

To avoid this situation, whenever the node comes back up online its best practice to do a "nodetool repair" or run queries with consistency "local_quorum" to get consistent data back.

Also remember, consistency "ONE" is comparable to uncommitted read (dirty read) in the world of RDBMS (WITH UR). So expect to see unexpected data.

Comment: Hinted handoff was disabled in this case. I'd like to understand your answer in reference to what has been given in the following link: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsRead.html

Comment: I'm not able to understand why read repair is not happening completely? In the link provided, it's written that "the coordinator sends a digest request to all remaining replicas." So even if I'll not get all the rows the very first time I run the program, why am I not getting the complete data in the next execution? I was expecting the read repair to have made the data consistent.

Comment: With consistency "ONE" read repair doesn't even happen, as there no other node to compare it with. Here is the documentation on it http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html. Even in case of consistency "local_quorum" or "quorum" there is a read_repair_chance set at the table level which s default to 0.1. Which means only 10% of reads will trigger read_repair. This is to save performance by not triggering every time.  Think about it, if read repair can bring the table entirely consistent across nodes, then why does "nodetool repair" even exist?

Comment: My observations don't support your statement that "With consistency "ONE" read repair doesn't even happen" because after running the program, when I checked Node 2(which was down at the time of writing), it contained some rows(not all). Therefore, some repair must have happened because hinted handoff was off.

Comment: We can't proceed with just observations further.  So closing this for now.

Answer (score 1):

[Per documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntConfigConsistency.html), consistency level `ONE` when reads:

> Returns a response from the closest replica, as determined by the snitch. By default, a read repair runs in the background to make the other replicas consistent.  Provides the highest availability of all the levels if you can tolerate a comparatively high probability of stale data being read. The replicas contacted for reads may not always have the most recent write.

Did you check that your code contacted the node that always was online & accepted writes?

The [DSE Architecture guide](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/index.html), and especially [Database Internals](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntTOC.html) section provides good overview how Cassandra works.

Comment: Yes. I had given only one IP as the contact point in the code(the IP was of the node which contained all the entries)

Comment: @VishalSharma Passing one node shouldn't matter, as first thing driver figures out is the entire cluster topology ( i.e. all the nodes (ip) in that cluster).